# Scorch mark behind the control knob of a stove top element

Tags: stove, range

What would cause a scorch mark behind the control knob of an electric stove top element? What repair would be needed?

Comment: It's really hard to say - can you provide a detailed picture (edit your post with it)

Comment: The controller may be overheating. If it is hot enough to make a scorch mark it would be very hot and could burn fingers if touched, but to test it you could remove the knob and turn the element on halfway. Carefully feel the area around the shaft and see if it heats up. If this is happening, compare to other burners which have no scorch marks. You can get a new controller for your range for $50 to $100.

Comment: I really don’t think anyone could truly answer the question without the brand and model.